# Arranging cups and saucers so the colors does not clash

Tags: probability

Six cups and saucers come in pairs: there are two cups and saucers which
are red, two white and two black. If the cups are randomly placed onto the
saucers (one each), find the probability that no cup is on a saucer of the same
colour.

My attempt at an answer. First two saucers are red ,then white and then black.

4/6*3/5*2/4*1/3*1*1 = 1/15

I feel this could be done by combinations or multiplied by a factorial because it can be done in more than this way.

Comment: Are the saucers fixed? Or can we move them around as well?

Comment: @Gummy bears This only changes the way you perform the calculation (e.g. the order in which you consider the different saucer colors), but not the actual result.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955019/on-the-probability-of-placing-cups-on-saucers

Answer (score 1):

Try using the complementary event : "There is at least one collision" (let's call it event C). It will be easier to go about (and then you'll calculate $1-P(C)$ to obtain the probability you want).

In order to be sure that you are not counting equivalent setups twice, we can further decompose this event into "Exactly $n$ collisions" (call them $C_n$). All $C_n$ are mutually exclusive, so you'll just have to add up their probability.

Which values of $n$ are meaningful anyway ? And for each of these values, what are the specific possible setups ?

Comment: this is actually a better approach as calculating the probability of the complement event is far more easier.

Comment: People call Charles should rule the world.

Answer (score 1):

The red saucers have either two black cups; two white cups; or one of each.
For each case, decide what the other saucers must have.
For each case, count how many ways cups $R1,R2,W1,W2,B1,B2$ can be assigned to saucers $r1,r2,w1,w2,b1,b2$.